# Creating a new record, then focusing on the new record

Tags: c#, database

So far I have the following code on a button click event:

```
        string AccRef = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("New Customer", "Customer Reference:", "", 0, 0);

        if (AccRef != "")
        {
            DataRow dr = dSSystem.Customers.NewRow();
            dr["AccRef"] = AccRef;
            dSSystem.Customers.Rows.Add(dr);


            frmCustomer frmCust = new frmCustomer();
            frmCust.ShowDialog();

            this.customersTableAdapter.Fill(this.dSSystem.Customers);
        }
```

This successfully creates a new row as I can see behind the dialogue, however, I have an issue - the dialog that displays is another form that displays all the customer information, this is handled with text boxes having a data binding to the appropriate fields within the database, so naturally they display the information on the selected record within the DB, at the moment however it's showing the information for the previously selected record and not moving to the one created using the code above.

How do I make the system create a new row and then focus on the new row before opening the new form for editing?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is there a unique id involved (AccRef?) that we can use to locate the correct row in the dialog-form?

Comment: An account reference is involved yes, each record has a unique one. How can I jump to a record with a particular reference? I'm using a binding source with my data set.

Comment: I've added to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially you can pass information to the dialog-form, which that form can use to navigate to the correct record.

The simplest approach is to create a constructor for the second form that accepts an argument.

```
public frmCustomer(int newID)
{
    InitializeComponent(); 
    // use newID (if present) to navigate
    // to the correct row
}

frmCustomer frmCust = new frmCustomer(theNewID);
frmCust.ShowDialog();
```

I don't know the details of your binding, so cannot advise how you would navigate to the record.

There are a number of other approaches, [outlined here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14122/Passing-Data-Between-Forms).

A simplistic approach could be to open the dialog-form at the *next new record* and navigate back a row but, again, I don't know your set-up enough to offer code for this. If you have a `BindingSource` you can use its methods `MoveLast()` or `MovePrevious()`.

If you use the first approach and the 2nd form opens with the passed id, then you can use the `Find` method of the `BindingSource`, and then the `Position` property to move to the found record. See the example [here at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms158165.aspx).

Comment: So once I open the new form, the code above should bring in this ID and be able to use it as a variable?

Comment: Yes. I'm just eating some chips.. :)